# how to invoke defined targets in the same Makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile, target

here is the Makefile（Unix Shell）

```
main : mainFunc.c
    gcc -c -o main.o mainFunc.c
other : otherSum.c
    gcc -c -o other.o otherSum.c
link : other.o main.o
    gcc -o main.out other.o main.o
```

how to invoke them in another new target

I've tried like this:

```
doAll : 
    make main
    make other
    make link
```

indeed the main.out has been built out

but there are more lines like "make[1]：leaving/entering the directory ……"

I want to know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a poorly written makefile.

The `main` target should be `main.o` to correspond to the file being created rather than being a random (phony) target only vaguely connected to the actual work.

Similarly for the `other` and `link` targets which should be `other.o` and `main.out` respectively.

Instead of manually running `make` from the body of the `doAll` target those targets could be listed as prerequisites of the `doAll` target (i.e. `doAll: main other link`) and them make would handle it correctly.

That being said, if my first suggestions were followed and the targets themselves were corrected then listing `main.o` and `other.o` as prerequisites of `doAll` would not even be necessary since listing `main.out` would automatically chain the targets up correctly.

And going even one step farther still, you could get rid of all those actual rules entirely and let the built-in rules do the work for you. All you need to do is rename the `main.out` target to `main`, delete the `main.o` and `other.o` targets entirely and remove the rule body from the `main: other.o main.o` target definition (making it a prerequisite definition only).

That is to say that a makefile consisting of nothing more than:

```
main: other.o main.o
```

will correctly build the project your makefile above is building but without the unnecessary re-invocations of make and the manual chaining of targets/etc. Using this you could even still specify your own compilation and linking flags using the built-in variables `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, and `LDLIBS`.

Oh, and to answer the question of 'Why do I get "make[1]：leaving/entering the directory ……" with this makefile?'

It has to do with make detecting recursion and trying to help you know what is happening. You can suppress it with the `--no-print-directory` option.

Comment: Thanks for your outspoken criticisms!

Comment: @qweeah Apologies if the tone came off a bit too strong. That was not my intention.